# MPLAB X __delay_ms() hangs on PIC16F77A

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, mplabx, pic16f877a

I'm trying to use the __delay_ms() function to make an LED blink on the PIC16F77A. 

The reason I think it stalls on the __delay_ms() function is because whatever I set RB0 to before the delay function always works, while anything after it doesn't (for any value I pass in). 


I'm using a PICKit3 and MPLAB X to program my board. I have a 10k pullup on MCLR and a 16MHz oscillator with two 22pF capacitors in parallel on pins 13 and 14 of the PIC, and RB3/PGM wired to ground (basically the same setup as in this [tutorial](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/led-blinking-with-pic-microcontroller)). I've also tried this with a 20MHz oscillator (with 22pF and 33pF capacitors, as specified in the datasheet).

```
#include <xc.h>

// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
//END CONFIG

#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000


void main()
{
    TRISB0 = 0; //RB0 as Output PIN
    while(1) {
        RB0 = 0;
        __delay_ms(1000);
        RB0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code above leaves the LED off. If instead I put `RB0 = 1` before `RB0 = 0`, it leaves the LED on.

Answer (score 2):

> i.e. The code above should ultimately turn the LED on, but it stays
>   off. –

It doesn't. the PIC probably reset after reaching the end and re-enter the main method. If you want to stop after the last line, add a while (1); at the end.

---

With 2 times 10ms delay, you would hardly see a LED light up, especially you are not in a loop.

First, put your code in a loop like so so that it keeps executing and only select the pin you want as output:

```
void main()
{
    TRISB0bits.TRISB0 = 0; //RB0 as Output PIN

while (1) {
    RB0 = 0;
    __delay_ms(10);
    RB0 = 1;
    __delay_ms(10);
}
}
```

Then you state:

> I have a 10k pulldown on MCLR

You need a 10k pullup, not pulldown.

For the oscillator, try first to use the internal oscillator to make sure you don't have issues in this regard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I misspoke when I said I have a 10k pulldown; it's connected as a pullup.
I think my example was also somewhat poor. If I have something like this, the LED stays on, but if I swap the order of the LED toggle (i.e. instead have RB0 = 0, then RB0 = 1), it stays off.
`while(1) {
        RB0 = 1;
        __delay_ms(1000);
        RB0 = 0;
        __delay_ms(1000);
    }
`